# Snap lines to polygon verticies at interscetion

Tags: postgis, grass-gis, intersection, topology, snapping

I'm trying to figure out a way to snap lines to a polygon layer, but only at the intersecting point.  Here is a sample picture of what I'm working with.  I have a layer of polygons and a line string layer. [image]

My goal is to create a topology from the polygons, thin the verticies, and then snap the line layer to polygon verticies within some threshold (i.e. 20 meters).  However, I haven't figured out a way to do this using any of my available software, which is QGIS, Grass 7, and PostGIS.  Ultimately I would like to be able to make changes to say the polygon layer, and have those changes affect the line string layer, but still be able to differentiate the layers and all their attributes.  I have tried various tools in GRASS to no avail, and have only just begun to learn and investigate PostGIS.

Does anyone have suggestions on ways to accomplish this task using these open source tools?  Even multi-step, more complex solutions would be welcome, as I hope to eventually script this work flow as much as possible.

Comment: check out the postgis function st_snaptogrid

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a set of basins and stream network that were created in some non-standard way, such that the stream endpoints do not intersect with the basin drain points. At the outset, be aware that efforts like this to manipulate dirty data often end in frustration...

Here's an outline in GRASS of some steps that might help to "fix" the situation. I'm assuming that the direction of the stream lines is always downstream, i.e. that the endpoint of each stream line is actually the downstream end of the reach.

1. First add two columns to the streams vector: end_x and end_y, then use the  `v.to.db` module, with `option=end` to get the current (wrong) coordinates of each reach endpoint.
2. Export these two columns with `v.out.ascii` and pipe back into `v.in.ascii` to get a points vector of the current endpoints.
3. Again add two columns to this new endpoints vector `snap_x, snap_y`. Then run the module v.distance with the option `upload=to_x,to_y` and the `to=` parameter will be the basins layer. This will add to the endpoints vector the x,y coordinates at the nearest vertex in the basins polygons.
4. Next, another `v.out.ascii ... | v.in.ascii` to create a second points vector of the correct drainage points that should lie on the basins boundary. Be sure to specify correctly the x,y columns in the v.in.ascii part to get the snap_x and snap_y columns.
5. Finally `v.distance` from streams to the new points vector, where you specify `output=connectors` . And `v.patch` to merge the streams with the connectors.  This should leave you with streams line vector that includes a small line segment from the (incorrect) end of each reach to the actual basin drain points. You can then try `v.generalize` or `v.clean tool=snap` to join these small segments to the rest of the stream reach.

Comment: These are streams and catchments.  They are generated using the TauDEM tool set, from 10 meter DEM's.  The streams should intersect the catchments at the drainage point, but TauDEM doesn't add an explicit vertex to either the stream or the catchment at this point.  I'm using these to build a model mesh, and need to simplify some features for computational efficiency without loosing too much geographic data in the processes.  We have a current work flow using ArcGIS topology editing, and I'm trying to find a way to get out from under ArcGIS to achieve similar results.